# Find a remainder when dividing some number $n\in \mathbb N$ with 30

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> A number n when you divide with 6 give a remainder 4, when you divide with 15 the remainder is 7. How much is remainder when you divide number $n$ with $30$?

that mean $n=6k_1+4$, $n=15k_2+7$, and $n=30k_3+x$, so I need to find  $x$. And $30=6*5$ or I can write $30=2*15$, maybe this can do using congruence bit I stuck there if I use that $4n\equiv x \pmod{30}$, and I can write $n\equiv x\pmod{2*15}$, since  $n\equiv 7 \pmod{15}$ and using little Fermat's little theorem  $ n\equiv 1 \pmod 2 $ so then $n\equiv 7 \pmod{30}$ is this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename $k_1\to a$ and $k_2 \to b$. We have: $$6a +4 = 15b+7\implies 2a=5b+1 \implies b=2c+1$$ So $$n = 15(2c+1)+7 = 30c+22$$ so $x=22$.

Answer (score 1):

$n\equiv4\pmod6\implies n\equiv4\pmod3\equiv1\  \ \ \  (1)$

$n\equiv4\pmod6\implies n\equiv4\pmod2\equiv0\  \ \ \  (2)$

$n\equiv7\pmod{15}\implies n\equiv7\pmod3\equiv1\  \ \ \  (1)$

$n\equiv7\pmod{15}\implies n\equiv7\pmod5\equiv2\  \ \ \  (3)$

Apply [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) on $(1),(2),(3)$

Alternatively,

$n\equiv7\pmod{15}\implies n=15k+7$ where $k$ is any integer

$15k+7\equiv k+1\pmod2\implies k$ must be odd  $=2m+1$(say)

$n=15(2m+1)+7$

Comment: Perhaps it should be mentioned explicitly that the remainders are indeed compatible, as the two remainders mod 3 coincide. This is not always the case. The second approach as written would also work if the first remainder were 2.

Comment: @LutzL, Thanks for your valuable feedback

Answer (score 1):

$n\equiv 7\pmod{\!15}\!\iff\! n\equiv 7,\color{#c00}{22}\pmod{\!30}\,$ $\Rightarrow\,n\equiv 1,\color{#c00}4\pmod{6}$

Answer (score 0):

Numbers that have remainder $4$ by division with $6$ are
$$
...-8,~-2,~4,~ 10,~ 16,~ 22,~ 28,~ 34,~ 40,~ 46,~ 52,~ 58,~...
$$
Numbers that have remainder $7$ by division with $15$ are
$$
...,-8,~ 7,~ 22,~ 37,~ 52,~ ...
$$
Common in both sequences are
$$
-8,~ 22,~ 52
$$
Now detect and confirm the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$n\equiv 4 \pmod{6} \Rightarrow 5n\equiv 20 \pmod{30};\\
n\equiv 7 \pmod{15} \Rightarrow 2n\equiv 14 \pmod{30}.$$
Add the two:
$$7n \equiv 34\equiv 4 \pmod{30} \Rightarrow \\
91n\equiv n\equiv 52 \equiv 22 \pmod{30}.$$

Comment: If you take the difference here you get $3n\equiv 6 \bmod 30$ and since $3$ is a factor of $30$ you get $n\equiv 2 \bmod 10$ which offers $2, 12 , 22$ to try in the original equations.

Comment: @MarkBennet, thank you for suggesting the good shortcut, but I want to minimize wordiness and make it self-explanatory.

Comment: @Mark & farruhota Also, because $\,\ldots \Rightarrow 7n\equiv 4$ is a *unidirectional* arrow, the argument only deduces that $\,n\equiv 22\,$ is *necessary.* It need not  be *sufficient*, so we need to *check* it *is* a solution. (vs. an extraneous root). This is a common beginner error so it is worth explicit mention in answers. But here it is simpler to check the two possibilities $n\equiv 7\pmod{\!15}\!\iff\! n\equiv 7,\color{#c00}{22}\pmod{\!30}\,$ as in my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque Noted: you will see that in my comment I did refer to checking back in the original equations. And yes, reducing more quickly to two possibilities rather than three is more efficient.

Comment: @Mark Yes, I saw that. For balance - I sought to "maximize wordiness" to help readers avoid that pitfall!

Comment: @BillDubuque I think we are agreed that it is a point worth emphasising.

Comment: @BillDubuque, thank you for remarking (constructive criticism). However, if there was an extraneous root, which neeeded to be rejected, I would have shown it (like you did by coloring). For example, $\sqrt{2-x}=x \Rightarrow 2-x=x^2 \Rightarrow x_1=-2, x_2=\color{red}{1} \Rightarrow x=\color{red}{1}$. If not rejected, it is the correct/final root. This is the general agreement.

Comment: @farruhota The problem is that without an *explicit* remark like "one easily checks that $n\equiv 22$ satisfies the original equations" there is no way for the reader to judge if the author has made the common mistake described above. If a student handed in the above answer as homework they would likely lose credit for that reason. In other cases this single possibility might indeed be an extraneous root,  i.e. no solution exists. You have to check that when using *unidirectional* inferences.